# Could somebody help me figure out the error in my code? (Python basic GUI)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, syntax-error

I've only recently dipped my toes into python (only ever coded in java and JS) and thought I would try my hand at making a simple number pad GUI. I'm still getting used to the indentation format.

I've applied proper indenting and fixed all typos and syntax errors but still receive the following error

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Lab Work/Lab 1/Number Pad test GUI.py", line 4, in 
    class BaseWindow(tkinter.Tk):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Lab Work/Lab 1/Number Pad test GUI.py", line 8, in BaseWindow
    self.minsize (x,y)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined"

I have updated the code below to my latest version also

```
import tkinter, tkinter.ttk as ttk
import random

class BaseWindow(tkinter.Tk):
    def _Change (self):
        x,y = self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height()

    self.minsize (x, y); self.maxsize(x, y)
    #This locks window size when called

    def FgridFormatButtons (self, ButtonList, NewLineAmount = 3):
        self.Row = 0
        self.Col = 0

        for Button in ButtonList:
            Button.grid(row = self.Row, column = self.Col)

            self.Col += 1

            if self.Col == NewLineAmount:
                self.Row += 1
                self.Col = 0
                continue

class Window (BaseWindow):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        #Main method code

        self.EntryFrame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.PadFrame = ttk.Frame(self)

        self.EntryFrame.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.PadFrame.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

        self.AllButtons = []
        self.CanWrite = true

        self.Cod = args.get("Code") or random.randrange(9999)
        self.Timer = args.get("Timer") or 2000

        print ("debug %d"% self.Code)

        for x in range (1,10):
            self.AllButtons.append(ttk.Button(self.PadFrame, width = 4, text = x, command = lambda y = x: self.Update(x)))
            self.bind(str(x), lambda CatchEvent, y = x: self.Update(y))

        self.FGridFormatButtons(self.AllButtons)

        self.ZeroButton = ttk.Button (self.PadFrame, width = 4, text = 0, command = lambda: self.Update(0))
        self.SubmitButton = ttk.Button(self.PadFrame, width = 4, text = "Ent", command = self.CheckCode)
        self.ClearButton = ttk.Button(self.PadFrame, width = 4, text = "C", command = lambda: self.Update(-1))

        self.ClearButton.grid(row = self.Row, column = 0)
        self.ZeroButton.grid(row = self.Row, column = 1)
        self.SubmitButton.grid(row = self.Row, column = 2)

        self.bind ("0", lambda CatchEvent: self.Update(0))
        self.bind("<return>", lambda CatchEvent: self.CheckCode())

        self.KeyEnter = ttk.Entry(self,EntryFrame, state ="disabled")
        self.KeyEnter.pack

        #--
        self.after (5, self._Change)
        #This will wait 5 miliseconds and then lock the window
        #If your computer takes longer than 5 miliseconds to load then kill yourself. Or alternatively, change the last value to match how long it takes

def Update (self, x):
    if self.CanWrite:
        self.KeyEnter["state"] = "normal"

        if x == 1:
            self.KeyEnter.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        else:
            self.KeyEnter.insert(tkinter.END, x)

        self.KeyEnter["state"] = 'disabled'

def CheckCode(self):
    Key = self.KeyEnter.get()

    self.Update(-1)

    if Key == str(self.Code):
        self.Update("Correct Code!")
        self.after(self.Timer, self.destroy)

    else:
        self.Update("Incorrect code")

    self.ChangeWritePerms()

    self.after(self.Timer, self.ChangeWritePerms)

def ChangeWritePerms(self):
    if self.CanWrite:
        self.CanWrite = False
    else:
        self.CanWrite = True
        self.Update(-1)


window().mainloop()


class BaseWindow(tkinter.Tk):
    def _change (self):
        x,y = self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height()

    self.minimize (x,y)
        #This locks window size when called

    def FgridFormatButtons (self, ButtonList, NewLineAmount = 3):
        self.Row = 0
        self.Col = 0

        for Button in ButtonList:
            Button.grid(row = self.Row, column = self.Col)

            self.Col += 1

            if self.Col == NewLineAmount:
                self.Row += 1
                self.Col = 0
                continue

class Window (BaseWindow):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        #Main method code

        self.EntryFrame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.PadFrame = ttk.Frame(self)

        self.EntryFrame.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.PadFrame.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

        self.AllButtons = []
        self.CanWrite = true

        self.Cod = args.get("Code") or random.randrange(9999)
        self.Timer = args.get("Timer") or 2000

        print ("debug %d"% self.Code)

        for x in range (1,10):
            self.AllButtons.append(ttk.Button(self.PadFrame, width = 4, text = x, command = lambda y = x: self.Update(x)))
            self.bind(str(x), lambda CatchEvent, y = x: self.Update(y))

        self.FGridFormatButtons(self.AllButtons)

        self.ZeroButton = ttk.Button (self.PadFrame, width = 4, text = 0, command = lambda: self.Update(0))
        self.SubmitButton = ttk.Button(self.PadFrame, width = 4, text = "Ent", command = self.CheckCode)
        self.ClearButton = ttk.Button(self.PadFrame, width = 4, text = "C", command = lambda: self.Update(-1))

        self.ClearButton.grid(row = self.Row, column = 0)
        self.ZeroButton.grid(row = self.Row, column = 1)
        self.SubmitButton.grid(row = self.Row, column = 2)

        self.bind ("0", lambda CatchEvent: self.Update(0))
        self.bind("<return>", lambda CatchEvent: self.CheckCode())

        self.KeyEnter = ttk.Entry(self,EntryFrame, state ="disabled")
        self.KeyEnter.pack

        #--
        self.after (5, self._Change)
        #This will wait 5 miliseconds and then lock the window
        #If your computer takes longer than 5 miliseconds to load then kill yourself. Or alternatively, change the last value to match how long it takes

def Update (self, x):
    if self.CanWrite:
        self.KeyEnter["state"] = "normal"

        if x == 1:
            self.KeyEnter.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        else:
            self.KeyEnter.insert(tkinter.END, x)

        self.KeyEnter["state"] = 'disabled'

def CheckCode(self):
    Key = self.KeyEnter.get()

    self.Update(-1)

    if Key == str(self.Code):
        self.Update("Correct Code!")
        self.after(self.Timer, self.destroy)

    else:
        self.Update("Incorrect code")

    self.ChangeWritePerms()

    self.after(self.Timer, self.ChangeWritePerms)

def ChangeWritePerms(self):
    if self.CanWrite:
        self.CanWrite = False
    else:
        self.CanWrite = True
        self.Update(-1)


window().mainloop()
```

Comment: You're missing a colon on the end of `def_change (self)` on the line before the error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment David, I already tried that but it just returns this error instead
  , line 5
    def_change (self):
                     ^

Comment: Sorry - didn't spot you have an underscore between `def` and `change`

Comment: If you're going to update the question, you should update the code to the version you are currently using - incidentally, you have the code duplicated in the question. Also, unless you mark the error as code (either with backticks or by indenting it), part of it is not visible in your question. Take a look at the [editing help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how to do this if you're not sure.

Comment: Oh, and you're missing a comma after `"<return>"`

Comment: I've fixed my formatting above after your advice, and applied some fixes to my code. Thanks for the advice too, my formatting was disgusting to be fair :)

Comment: I appreciate that you're new to Python, but this isn't the way that Stack Overflow works. The idea is that you do your very best to debug your code, but ask a single question if you get stuck. You can't keep updating your question with error after error. The current one in the question is because you have got the failing line indented incorrectly. Add 4 spaces. Your next issue will be that you have `window().mainloop()` which should probably be `window = tkinter.Tk()` followed by `window.mainloop()` If this still doesn't work, you should carry on debugging yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you change your question.
Try to change tkinter.tk into tkinter.Tk with big T.

This error shows that you forgot to put comma before lambda function.

```py
"line 60 self.bind("" lambda CatchEvent: self.CheckCode()) ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
```

Have you tried to add comma ? 
Check line 5 and 110 you forget space after def and colon at the end function argument. 
Check line 86 too, you defined key as Key in line 82, so you have to call it Key with big K in line 86.
Check line 88, it shows `self.;after`. Please delete the semicolon to avoid syntax error too. 
What is the text editor you are using ? If you use vscode, it will show the error with red underline.

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time to answer. By the time you had left this comment I had already made all the fixes you have suggested. I now get the error 
" line 4, in <module>
    class BaseWindow(tkinter.tk):
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'tk'"

I'm currently writing this in thonny on my Pi, I know there are better options around but I chose this specifically to practice writing python on my Pi :)

Comment: Oh, that's fine. It's great that your question already answered. Have you try to change it into tkinter.Tk with big T for the recent error ?

Comment: applied your fix (which worked) then i received a number of other errors which I have now fixed. But now I receive another error. I've updated my code above and put the new error there. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: have you try to check line 5 and 110 for missing space after def and missing colon at the end of function argument ?

Comment: I added the spaces and the colon but it still returns this error:                         

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Lab Work/Lab 1/Number Pad test GUI.py", line 4, in <module>
    class BaseWindow(tkinter.Tk):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Lab Work/Lab 1/Number Pad test GUI.py", line 8, in BaseWindow
    self.minsize (x,y)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: is self.minsize part of _Change function ?

Answer (score 0):

include "self.minsize (x, y); self.maxsize(x, y)" inside the function
any statement inside the class must be inside a function
Ex: import tkinter, tkinter.ttk as ttk
import random

class BaseWindow(tkinter.Tk):
    def _Change (self):
        x,y = self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height()
        self.minsize (x, y); self.maxsize(x, y)